# In C#, how do you programmatically open a link with a specific browser?

Tags: c#, browser, hyperlink, safari, web

For example, the user has multiple browsers: Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, and the user's default browser is Chrome. How can I make it so that when the code opens the user a link, it will use Safari instead of his default browser, which is Chrome? Is that even possible? Thanks :)

Comment: you can use ``Process.Start()`` and you need to specify the browser name in it which you want to open, For Safari use its exe name like ``Process.Start("safari.exe","http://www.stackoverflow.com")``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Chrome.exe", "http://www.stackoverflow.com");//or firefox.exe
```

You might have exceptions if the browser is not configured correctly. So it is better to catch the exception like this:

```
try
{
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Chrome.exe", "http://www.stackoverflow.com");//or firefox.exe

}
catch(System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception noBrowser)
{
    if (noBrowser.ErrorCode == -2147467259)
       MessageBox.Show(noBrowser.Message);
}
catch (System.Exception other)
{
      MessageBox.Show(other.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When application is going to start or **Global.asax** event, we should handle this scenario than only we can redirect to request to any client browser. This trick should not even try with **page events.**

Use the nameSpace and add the code in global page : *process.Start()*